# What pump to use to pump latex?

Tags: pumps

I am trying using pump to promote circulation of latex solution in a latex dipping tank. Is there any pump that suits this purpose? Also, is there any better ideas to promote circulation of the latex in the latex tank without handling the solution vigorously.
The explanation of main process can be found in this link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTIADlYOkNc

Comment: Use a stirrer and regulate the speed.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a flat plate stirrer or a helix depending on what you wish to achieve.

Controlling the speed of rotation will be useful as well.